# how to make a property optional but not undefined in typescript

Tags: typescript, object, interface

when you create a typescript interface with an optional property like this:

```
interface X {
 a?: string
}
```

here `x.a` is of type `string | undefined`
so typescript will complain of the following code:

```
function stringValue(value: string):void{}
function test(x:X){
 // error, because stringValue() only accepts strings
 stringValue(x.a)
}
```

but, if Typescript knows `x.a` value in advance, why it still complains?

```
function test(x:X){
  x = { a:"string value" }
  // now x.a is string, not string | undefined
  // so the following code must be valid
  // but TS still complains

  stringValue(x.a)
  
  // this is a workaround but out of my question's scope
  stringValue(x.a as string)
}
```

how to tell typescript that the consumer of our function doesn't have to provide a value for `x.a`
but we assign a default value to it, so it cannot be an undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not narrow down the type of `x` when a new object with a property `a` that is definitely not undefined is assigned to it. Its type remains `X`, and that is why you get the error.

This compiles, but it mutates `x`:

```js
function test(x: X) {
    x.a = "string value";
    stringValue(x.a);
}
```

But this is probably not what you want: you are not assigning a default value for `x.a`, instead, you are *replacing* the value of `x.a` that you get from the argument. In other words, your `test` function is the same as calling `stringValue("string value")`.

The correct way to provide a default value would be:

```js
function test(x: X) {
    stringValue(x.a ?? "string value");
}
```

Comment: what `x.a ?? "string value"` means?

Comment: `??` is the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator). It returns the left operand if it is not null or undefined, and the right operand otherwise.